# Serialization and Deserialization of generic Map for Java and external use

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a `Map<String, Object>` which I am using as a mapping for a JSON document, however want to create and maintain Java type information at the same time as retaining the structure of the document.

I'm attempting to use Jackson to create the document and it seems to work fine but I'm seeing something strange when attempting to deserialize it.  A very simple serialization example:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE, JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY);
final Map<String, Object> map = Maps.newHashMap();
map.put("test", new Date());
final String ser = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
final Map<String, Object> deser = mapper.readValue(ser, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>(){});
System.err.println(deser.get("test").getClass());
```

Gives the serialized form `{"test":1410721662084,"@class":"java.util.Date"}` which seems fine but when deserializing returns the type of "test" to be `Long`.

If I change the type serialization to use `WRAPPER_ARRAY` rather than `EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` then the type of "test" is correctly returned as `Date`, but doing this alters the structure of the JSON document so is not something I'm allowed to do.  How do I retain the structure of the document as well as allow deserialization back to the correct types?

This is against Jackson 2.4.2.

Comment: Interesting problem.  It would be more fun to try and figure this out without a custom deserializer, but if that proves impossible is a custom deserializer an option?

Answer (score 0):

Deserialization with maps is always tricky as maps don't preserve type information, which makes Jackson resort to `@class` and that not something you usually want. Instead, you can create a simple class:

```
public class TestClass {
   private Date test;
   //getters and setters omitted 
}
```

This class has concrete structure and JSON will serialize it as

```
{ "test" : 1410721662084}
```

which is much cleaner and type-safe representation of your object. Then you just need to pass `TestClass.class` to `readValue()` method and your `test` attribute will be magically converted to proper type (`Date`)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not able to definitively state which objects will be placed in the `Map` so cannot go down this route.  As explained in the question, the sample code is to highlight the issue rather than representative of the problem I'm attempting to solve.  Although I recognise the drawbacks I really do want Jackson to use the `@class` information when deserializing, but it isn't doing so.

Comment: @jgm will your external client also use Jackson? because using the `@class` properties will make it jackson-dependent.

Comment: No they will ignore the `@class` properties.